# Http response code 500/ FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

when I try to get the input stream from an URL, I get the following Error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://...
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
W/System.err:     at com.andrei.mobilissimoro.MainActivity$FeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:406)
W/System.err:     at com.andrei.mobilissimoro.MainActivity$FeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:371)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

And the response code is 500.
Here is the code:

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
            try {
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(feed).openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                Integer status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(status.toString());
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                feedModelList = parseFeed(inputStream);

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: its server issue

Answer (score 0):

Server will send 500 code, when there is some exception while executing code on server while responding to your API call.

Comment: The Url is not wrong, I hide it because it's secret. Other apps can parse the feed I am trying to parse.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Check updated answer. There must be something wrong on server side.

Comment: But it can't be. Other apps can parse the feed. I must do something wrong. Can you tellme how should the code look?